# prevent resizing columns from passing outside horizontal boundaries

Tags: c#, listview, resize, horizontal-scrolling, multiple-columns

In a C# Windows Application I have a ListView on a Form.

When the Form loads it adds 5 columns to the ListView and some items. 
I have the items loading in a way so that all of the columns fit inside the bounds of the ListView.

This is fine, but I need them to always stay within the bounds but at the same time for the user to be able to resize them.

The problem is that whenever I make a column bigger by dragging the column divider bar to the right, the column disappears and I need to use the horizontal scroll bar to go and find it and bring it back within the bounds.

What I want to happen is that whenever I make a column bigger, by dragging the column divider to the right, for this action to never push the other columns on the right outside of the bounds of the ListView.

Comment: Code is better than a description of code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using the DataGridView instead of the ListView.
With the DataGridView you can set the columns to fill so it will never scroll horizontally.